# Advent of Code 2017, Day 8 - Evaluate instructions to modify registers

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, parsing, c++14

This is my solution to [Advent of Code 2017, Day 8](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/8).

### Problem description

The task is to model a machine which has an unspecified number of registers which are accessed by name and contain integer values. The machine executes instructions which can modify the register values if a comparison succeeds.

> Each instruction consists of several parts: the register to modify,
>   whether to increase or decrease that register's value, the amount by
>   which to increase or decrease it, and a condition. If the condition
>   fails, skip the instruction without modifying the register. The
>   registers all start at 0. The instructions look like this:
>
> ```
> b inc 5 if a > 1
> a inc 1 if b < 5
> c dec -10 if a >= 1
> c inc -20 if c == 10
> ```
>
> […]
>
> You might also encounter `<=` (less than or equal to) or `!=` (not equal to).

Given a sequence of instructions as input, the output of the program should be

- the maximum register value at the end of execution
- the maximum value contained in any register at any time during execution

In the above example, these values are 1, and 10.

### My code

My program works by parsing each line of the input to an `Instruction` object which is passed to the `execute` method of a `Machine` object which evaluates the condition contained in the instruction and modifies its register values appropriately.

#### `machine.h`

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Machine {
public:
    using RegisterName = std::string;
    using RegisterValue = int;

    struct Instruction {
        enum class Operation { Inc, Dec };

        enum class Comparison {
            Equal, Unequal,
            Less, LessEqual,
            Greater, GreaterEqual
        };

        struct ParseError : public std::runtime_error {
            ParseError(const std::string& what_arg);
        };

        static Operation to_operation(const std::string&);
        static Comparison to_comparison(const std::string&);

        // evaluate "a <cmp> b"
        static bool evaluate(Comparison cmp, RegisterValue a, RegisterValue b);

        Instruction() = default;
        Instruction(const std::string& line);
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Instruction&);

        RegisterName target;
        Operation operation;
        RegisterValue operation_amount;
        RegisterName source;
        Comparison comparison;
        RegisterValue compare_value;
    };

    void execute(const Instruction&);
    RegisterValue max_value() const;
    RegisterValue all_time_max_value() const { return all_time_max_; }

private:
    RegisterValue all_time_max_{0};
    std::unordered_map<RegisterName, RegisterValue> registers_;
};
```

#### `machine.cpp`

```
#include "machine.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

Machine::Instruction::ParseError::ParseError(const std::string& what_arg)
  : std::runtime_error{what_arg}
{}

Machine::Instruction::Operation
Machine::Instruction::to_operation(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s == "inc") return Operation::Inc;
    if (s == "dec") return Operation::Dec;

    std::stringstream error;
    error << "Unknown operation: " << s;
    throw ParseError{error.str()};
}

Machine::Instruction::Comparison
Machine::Instruction::to_comparison(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s == "==") return Comparison::Equal;
    if (s == "!=") return Comparison::Unequal;
    if (s == "<" ) return Comparison::Less;
    if (s == "<=") return Comparison::LessEqual;
    if (s == ">" ) return Comparison::Greater;
    if (s == ">=") return Comparison::GreaterEqual;

    std::stringstream error;
    error << "Unknown comparison: " << s;
    throw ParseError{error.str()};
}

bool Machine::Instruction::evaluate(
    Comparison cmp, RegisterValue a, RegisterValue b)
{
    switch (cmp) {
    case Comparison::Equal:        return a == b;
    case Comparison::Unequal:      return a != b;
    case Comparison::Less:         return a <  b;
    case Comparison::LessEqual:    return a <= b;
    case Comparison::Greater:      return a >  b;
    case Comparison::GreaterEqual: return a >= b;
    }
}

Machine::Instruction::Instruction(const std::string& line)
{
    std::smatch line_match;
    if (!std::regex_match(line, line_match,
        std::regex{R"((\w+) (\w+) ([+-]?\d+) if (\w+) (\W+) ([+-]?\d+))"}
    )) {
        std::stringstream error;
        error << "Invalid format: " << line;
        throw ParseError{error.str()};
    }

    target = line_match[1];
    operation = to_operation(line_match[2]);
    operation_amount = stoi(line_match[3]);
    source = line_match[4];
    comparison = to_comparison(line_match[5]);
    compare_value = stoi(line_match[6]);
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Machine::Instruction& i)
{
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(input, line)) {
        Machine::Instruction dummy{line};
        std::swap(i, dummy);
    }
    return input;
}

Machine::RegisterValue Machine::max_value() const
{
    if (!registers_.size()) return 0;
    return std::max_element(std::begin(registers_), std::end(registers_),
        [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a.second < b.second; }
    )->second;
}

void Machine::execute(const Instruction& i)
{
    RegisterValue src{registers_[i.source]};
    if (Instruction::evaluate(i.comparison, src, i.compare_value)) {
        RegisterValue& target{registers_[i.target]};
        switch (i.operation) {
        case Instruction::Operation::Inc:
            target += i.operation_amount; break;
        case Instruction::Operation::Dec:
            target -= i.operation_amount; break;
        }
        if (target > all_time_max_) all_time_max_ = target;
    }
}
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include "machine.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Machine m;
    Machine::Instruction i;
    try {
        while (std::cin >> i) m.execute(i);
    } catch (const Machine::Instruction::ParseError& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << m.max_value() << '\n';
    std::cout << m.all_time_max_value() << '\n';
}
```

#### Example

```
$ cat instructions.txt 
b inc 5 if a > 1
a inc 1 if b < 5
c dec -10 if a >= 1
c inc -20 if c == 10
$ ./machine <instructions.txt 
1
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First impressions

It's clear and easy to read; the program structure is obvious.  There's not a lot to improve here!

### Prefer function objects to switching on enums

We can eliminate the `Operation` and `Comparison` enums and their associated switches by passing the function itself; that means less code to modify if the language changes.  Here's what I ended up with:

```
    using Operation = std::function<RegisterValue(RegisterValue, RegisterValue)>;
    using Comparison = std::function<bool(RegisterValue, RegisterValue)>;
```

```
Machine::Instruction::Operation
Machine::Instruction::to_operation(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s == "inc") return std::plus<RegisterValue>();
    if (s == "dec") return std::minus<RegisterValue>();

    std::stringstream error;
    error << "Unknown operation: " << s;
    throw ParseError{error.str()};
}

Machine::Instruction::Comparison
Machine::Instruction::to_comparison(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s == "==") return std::equal_to<RegisterValue>();
    if (s == "!=") return std::not_equal_to<RegisterValue>();
    if (s == "<" ) return std::less<RegisterValue>();
    if (s == "<=") return std::less_equal<RegisterValue>();
    if (s == ">" ) return std::greater<RegisterValue>();
    if (s == ">=") return std::greater_equal<RegisterValue>();

    std::stringstream error;
    error << "Unknown comparison: " << s;
    throw ParseError{error.str()};
}

void Machine::execute(const Instruction& i)
{
    RegisterValue src{registers_[i.source]};
    if (i.comparison(src, i.compare_value)) {
        RegisterValue& target{registers_[i.target]};
        target = i.operation(target, i.operation_amount);
        if (target > all_time_max_) all_time_max_ = target;
    }
}
```

The `evaluate()` function is no longer required and drops out of the code.

If the construction of new function objects for every instruction is a concern, we could make static members for them all, and return the appropriate one by reference, or have a static `std::map`, where we can use `at()` for the lookup, and pass or convert the `std::out_of_range` error if needed.

## Use formatted input instead of regular expressions

We don't need all the weight of regular expressions to parse this simple input format.  We can drop the `#include <regex>` and simplify our instruction reading:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Machine::Instruction& i)
{
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(input, line)) return input;
    std::string op_str, cmp_str, if_str;
    std::istringstream in{line};
    in >> i.target >> op_str >> i.operation_amount
       >> if_str >> i.source >> cmp_str >> i.compare_value;
    if (std::string dummy; if_str != "if" || !in || in >> dummy) {
        std::stringstream error;
        error << "Invalid format: " << line;
        throw Machine::Instruction::ParseError{error.str()};
    }
    i.operation = Machine::Instruction::to_operation(op_str);
    i.comparison = Machine::Instruction::to_comparison(cmp_str);
    return input;
}
```

## Does it make sense to print outputs if an instruction failed?

I reorganised `main()` to reduce the scope of `i` and to avoid printing result if we fail to parse (and to accept a fixed input, for my testing convenience):

```
int main()
{
    std::istringstream instructions{
        "b inc 5 if a > 1\n"
        "a inc 1 if b < 5\n"
        "c dec -10 if a >= 1\n"
        "c inc -20 if c == 10\n"
    };

    try {
        Machine m;
        Machine::Instruction i;
        while (instructions >> i) m.execute(i);
        std::cout << m.max_value() << '\n';
        std::cout << m.all_time_max_value() << '\n';
    } catch (const Machine::Instruction::ParseError& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
}
```

## Minor tweaks

- We can write `registers.empty()` instead of `!registers.size()`.